# Im learning python and found an issue while changing colors in python terminal

Tags: python-3.x, colors

I would like to stop painting the background right after the string, so it doesn't paint the rest of the terminal line as you can see below:

[image: code lines/terminal]

According to the professor, by using `"\033[m'` after the string it should stop the "background painting", but it only works if I put another string after it (I used a "." at the second line and it works). Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Try `\033[0m` to reset the colors.

Comment: i did it! but doesnt worked..

Comment: It should work.  I don't get the same output in Visual Studio Code (which it looks like you are using).  Could be a terminal configuration issue.  It has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: You're right, i tested it in pycharm and it worked. Thank you.